# How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

My Laptop is Acer 5742G with "Npilfy 802.11 wireless".

I have both windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10

Earlier when I had Ubuntu 12.04, the wireless was working fine, but after installing 12.10 wireless is not working at all, although it is still working in windows.

I am not able to see "Wireless Networks" in the **Network Manager** nor in the **Network Settings**.

This was the output I got for **rfkill**

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
2: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

This is a snapshot of my Additional Drivers settings.
[image: Drivers]

As you can see, the required driver for wireless is installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem looks similar to mine, and I think the new kernel and broadcom drivers are the connection.  I ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

and it worked for me on a Samsung netbook.

Comment: Why are you posting the same answer as that already existed?

Comment: these commands helped me, on ubuntu 14.04 LTS, But same issue occurs again and again on same machine, Is there any permanent fix for same?

Answer (score 16):

Please check:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is it's pci.id 14e4:4727? If so, this may be helpful:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing happened to me, and I believe my answer is more shifted towards the UI but I think it is basically the same thing as DrA proposed:

1. Install linux-headers-generic (via software center or terminal).
2. In sofware origins > Additional drivers tab, check "Do not use this driver" & apply.
3. Then check again to use Broadcomm propietary driver and apply.

In fact this also worked for me in another laptop that had issues with nvidia drivers.