# No WiFi on dell vostro 2520 after update to 12.10

Tags: wireless

I have installed 12.04 on a dell vostro 2520 (previously 11.10) and wifi is gone now but wired network remains. I've reviewed the other questions and tried [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560):

and some stuff but no luck yet. The following is the process so far so hopefully someone can help.

I have the Broadcom bcm43142 chip.

I have made sure in the bios that the wlan is turned on, and it appears the laptop does not have a wireless hardware switch, only the keyboard function shortcut which turns bluetooth on and off on the taskbar but there is no lightup of the wireless function on the laptop itself.

Dell does not appear to have any drivers for ubuntu and google does not appear to be much help :(
Perhaps someone can please provide the recovery disk ISO that originally came on the hard drive?

Thanks in advance!
.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem looks similar to mine, and I think the new kernel and broadcom drivers are the connection.  I ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

and it worked for me on my Acer Laptop.

Refer [How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working/215342#215342)
for more details.

Comment: these commands helped me, on ubuntu 14.04 LTS, But same issue occurs again and again on same machine, Is there any permanent fix for same?

Comment: Just needed to do this with my Dell Vostro 2520 on Ubuntu 18.04... linux-headers-generic were already installed but when I did 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
I had wifi!