# Wireless Firmware Missing on Acer 3690

Tags: networking, internet-connection

I have 12.04 on an Acer 3690 and everything works perfectly except for the wireless internet. It says "Firmware Missing". I've already done the additional drivers thing, and that didn't help. Any suggestions? I'm new to ubuntu, so make them easy to understand :) Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the `Firmware Missing` message. Also, which wireless adapter are you using?

Comment: In the network settings, under wireless is where it says firmware missing. I'm just using the built in wireless card in the Acer Aspire 3690

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but no harm in trying right?

I had a similar problem in my Acer laptop. I think the new kernel and broadcom drivers are the connection.  I ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

and it worked for me on my Acer Laptop.

Refer [How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working/215342#215342)
for more details.

Comment: I feel stupid asking this, but is that all one code to all be ran at the same time?

Comment: Refer to http://askubuntu.com/a/227403/67346 for a more simpler explanation

Comment: After I followed those directions, in the network settings "wired" and "wireless" have disappeared.My only option is proxy. And it also won't read the Ethernet cable now, what do I do?