# No wifi in 12.10 Broadcom BCM4313 Samsung RF511

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)
>   [Can’t connect to any wireless connection after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247993/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-connection-after-updating)

Well my wireless card worked just after install, and after a reboot no wireless card was detected, so I can't connect wirelessly. The results of `lspci -nn` are:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

And here is `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: samsung-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod`:

```
    Module                  Size  Used by
    parport_pc             32689  0 
    ppdev                  17074  0 
    rfcomm                 46620  12 
    bnep                   18141  2 
    ext2                   72881  1 
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32049  1 
    snd_hda_codec_realtek    78048  1 
    coretemp               13401  0 
    kvm_intel             132760  0 
    kvm                   414071  1 kvm_intel
    ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
    aesni_intel            51038  0 
    cryptd                 20404  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
    aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
    snd_hda_intel          33492  3 
    snd_hda_codec         134213  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
    snd_hwdep              17699  1 snd_hda_codec
    snd_pcm                96668  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
    snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
    snd_rawmidi            30513  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_seq                61555  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
    snd_timer              29426  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
    i915                  520621  3 
    drm_kms_helper         49113  1 i915
    drm                   288721  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
    i2c_algo_bit           13414  1 i915
    psmouse                95595  0 
    snd                    78921  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
    btusb                  22475  0 
    uvcvideo               76750  0 
    videobuf2_core         32852  1 uvcvideo
    soundcore              15048  1 snd
    videodev              120310  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
    videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
    samsung_laptop         14533  0 
    serio_raw              13216  0 
    mei                    40691  0 
    bluetooth             209249  22 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
    videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
    video                  19336  2 i915,samsung_laptop
    lpc_ich                17062  0 
    microcode              22804  0 
    joydev                 17458  0 
    mac_hid                13206  0 
    snd_page_alloc         18485  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
    lp                     17760  0 
    parport                46346  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
    hid_generic            12541  0 
    usbhid                 46987  0 
    hid                   100411  2 hid_generic,usbhid
    uas                    17845  0 
    usb_storage            48839  0 
    r8169                  61651  0
```

I'm not sure what all of the above means, but it was posted to help solve another wireless card issue so I thought it would be helpful to post it here.

Any help in getting my wireless working would be greatly appreicated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install third-party drivers from Broadcom. Even if you want to use `b43` (although your card is not in the list of supported and tested devices, this may require *forcing* `b43` to work on that card, I don't know), you'd need firmware from broadcom.

[Ubuntu has a page with instructions to handle Broadcom wireless cards](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx). So do other Linux distros, namely Arch Linux, which also describes [the state of Broadcom wireless cards](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless).

In short, [you need to install the `bcmwl` package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Installing_STA_drivers). (The page also lists `broadcom-sta`, which is the name used on my (non-Ubuntu) distro, I am not sure of what the difference is, but that does say to install `bcmwl`...)

Comment: The (proprietary) Broadcom drivers should be in `System Settings > Hardware > Additional Drivers`. Just a sidenote, I installed b43 after using the official drivers for a while and the signal strength isn't nearly as good as with the Broadcom drivers. Unless you need monitor mode functionality or something, stick with the official ones.

Comment: Seems that the driver just wasn't being started on startup. Soon as I ran 'sudo modprobe brcmsmac' the card came into action. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should then be working. I don't believe b43 and firmware is optimal for 14e4:4727.