# Broadcom Wireless BCM4313 on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)
>   [Can’t connect to any wireless connection after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247993/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-connection-after-updating)

Using wireless successfully on 2 DELL VOSTRO 3500 laptops.

Both have failed - second one after update today. Sending me here.

Instead of trying various installs and un-installs - can I simply wait for another 1 month?
Will the new kernel solve this issue?

Comment: @hhlp No, that's not OP's issue - wireless *was* working.

Comment: What makes you think it's a kernel issue. I think it probably has something to do with the `bcmwl-kernel-source` upgrade in Precise.

Answer (score 4):

The recent problem with BCM4313 cards seems to be related to an upgraded version of the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package. As a workaround, I suggest downgrading it to the previous version, by using the following steps.

- Run `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source` to remove the package.
- Install the older version

  ```
  sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source=5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6
  ```

Manual deb downloads are available from here: [32bit](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6_i386.deb), [64bit](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.38+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb). Install the downloaded file by double clicking.

- Lock the packages version to prevent updates.

  ```
  gksu gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/bcmwl-kernel-source
  ```

and paste in the pollowing

```
Package: bcmwl-kernel-source
Pin: version 5.100.82.38+bdcom*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

PS: The workaround has been adapted from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/923809/comments/25). Unfortunately, I've no way of testing it, so please, let me know if it works, ... or not.

Comment: I think this (good) answer belongs in [the duplicate question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247993/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-connection-after-updating).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using official 3.5.x Kernels for Precise and this finally fixed my WiFi issues with random routers I had. It cannot be true that a LTS has this major issue and that I (!) had to downgrade (not even upgrade) WiFi drivers.

Comment: If you are using 3.5.x Kernels in Ubuntu 12.04 you should follow this guide from @mikewhatever but make sure you are using version `5.100.82.112` and this .deb package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/bcmwl-kernel-source Version `5.100.82.38` will break your bluetooth (my headset was stuttering). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wait. You can install the new kernel now ([package has been available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise-updates/linux-image-generic-lts-quantal) for a few month) and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I think this (good) answer belongs in [the duplicate question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247993/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-connection-after-updating).