# Ubuntu 12.04 and WiFi access problem

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm having some issue with internet access. I've got a Samsung laptop with a Broadcom wireless card and Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Everything worked fine at the beginning, but recently, probably after some kernel update, I noticed that I don't receive any packets for few seconds. When I tried to look what's wrong I noticed I can't access to router (some cheap TP Link), even ping is failing. Router is ok, because I am able to access it from other devices, and even from my laptop from Windows. But this disconnecting is very annoying. Anyone has the same issue? Where can be the problem?

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. Device 051a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fc500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-b1-ff-ff-ef-00-1b
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

Comment: What encryption (if any) are you using to connect to the router? Also, please run the command `lspci -v` in a terminal and add the last section, which will say **Network Controller** at the top, to your question.

Comment: @Aaron I use only WEP. Problem is, I **can** access the Internet. Furthermore, when I use `nmap` to scan devices in LAN, it shows them properly, with router exception (because it acts as a gateway?). I'm updating question with `lspci -v` output.

Comment: It seems that this problem has been encountered(and solved) before.   Try the solution posted at http://askubuntu.com/questions/250858/broadcom-wireless-bcm4313-on-12-04-lts/250896#250896