# Bad WiFi range with BCM4313 Card

Tags: wireless, 13.04, broadcom

I have an HP-Envy-4 laptop(dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 8) with a BCM4313 Wireless card. The strength not great when close to the router. However, the WiFi works well on 
Windows 8. I tried installing the Broadcom STA Wireless driver but resulted in Wicd not detecting my WiFi connection.
What could be the issue and how can I resolve it?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Here is some additional information:

```
pooja@pooja-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo modprobe brcmsmac
pooja@pooja-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
pooja@pooja-HP-ENVY-4-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list all
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Results with bcmwl-kernel-source installed:

```
    lspci -k | grep wl
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1895
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1795
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth

```
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP ENVY 4 Notebook PC/1895, BIOS F.0C 07/09/2012
[    1.357432] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: RTL8411 at 0xffffc90000678000, 10:60:4b:d7:0d:f8, XID 08800800 IRQ 46
[    1.357436] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    6.354058] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.WMID.ESDT] (Node     ffff88015923fa78), AE_NOT_EXIST (20121018/psparse-537)
[    6.354064] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._Q42] (Node ffff88015926af28), AE_NOT_EXIST (20121018/psparse-537)
[   18.706491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   18.889924] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   18.899524] VGA switcheroo: detected switching method \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.ATPX handle
[   18.951570] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[   19.225219] eth1: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.20.155.1 (r326264)
[   30.119193] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: link down
[   30.119258] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   80.447063] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: link down
[   80.447120] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   81.937320] r8169 0000:07:00.2 eth0: link down
[   81.937376] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready

     rfkill list all
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
    1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
    3: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
    4: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: I could really use some help please!

Answer (score 0):

BCM4313 card is known for behaving extraordinarily bad in Ubuntu with a [ton of various drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94021/how-do-i-get-the-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-working-on-an-asus-1015px) with different problems.

The package with a driver that worked for me (HP g6 laptop) in 12.xx is `bcmwl-kernel-source`. In 13.04, however, it suffers from other problems, of which you can find in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286734/how-to-downgrade-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcmwl-kernel-source). The most recent answer at the moment of me writing this suggests that downgrading to 12.xx is the best option.

By sticking with `bcmwl-kernel-source` on Ubuntu 13.04, however, you will be able to connect to most Wi-Fi networks, so you can give it a try.

After installing the driver via `apt` or Ubuntu Software Center, enable it `Additional Drivers` tab of `Software & Updates`.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried installing the bcmwl-kernel-source, however it resulted in my WiFi network not being detected at all. So I had to go back to bcrmsmac.