# Ubuntu 14.04 slow connection with Broadcom wireless card

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, internet, broadcom

Few days ago I updated my laptop from 13.10 to 14.04 by reinstalling everything and I started having troubles with my Broadcom card. It was working well with previous version, so i don't know what is going wrong now.
By following wiki pages and other answers here is what i did:

- found out my model, which is `BCM43228 14e4:4359`
- installed dkms and bcmw-kernel-source from installation cd

At this point if I check with lsmod I see that module `wl`, which should be the one used by my card, is correctly loaded. I am able to connect to my network (after about 15 seconds), but the connection is extremely slow (can't even perform an apt-get update till the end).
What elese could I try? I need my laptop for my courses, so I would like to fix this issue as soon as possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and I'm about to try installing b43. Only do this if you are sure because I'm a total newb and I don't know what I'm talking about really. But basically I think this is an open source version. And that should be better because the developers can test and modify the drivers.
Here is a guide to installing:
http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-broadcom-b43-legacy-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

If you haven't already read this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Here is a totally different idea (rolling back the driver):
[How to downgrade Broadcom wireless drivers bcmwl-kernel-source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286734/how-to-downgrade-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcmwl-kernel-source)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I reinstalled Ubuntu using a usb wifi dongle and enabling 3rd party software download, so it automatically selected the right driver (which is still wl, so I don't know what actually changed) and now it seems to work properly. I suggest you to do the same, with ethernet is even better (unfortunately my laptop has no ethernet port).