# Ubuntu is not detecting wireless router Cisco dpc3825. Newbie to Ubuntu, can connect via Ethernet cable, but no wireless detection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, cisco

I am unable to see any wireless networks detected. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 on a Lenovo G780 laptop two days ago. I can use the internet through an ethernet cable connected to my Cisco DPC3825 wireless router, or through Windows 8 wirelessly, but Ubuntu is not detecting any wireless networks at all. Updating the drivers is also not working. When I try to activate the Broadcom STA wireless driver, I get the following output:

Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

### Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

Here are some of the other outputs:

iwconfig shows the following:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

lxcbr0    no wireless extensions.
```

---

rfkill list shows the following:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

lspci shows the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

---

lshw -C network shows the following:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:88:e3:98:9d:fa
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:d3900000-d393ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3800000-d3803fff
```

If any other commands/info will be helpful, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/250858/broadcom-wireless-bcm4313-on-12-04-lts/250896#250896

Comment: Unfortunately, the older version of bcmwl-kernel-source did not install correctly. It began building the module but did not finish. I got this error message specifically when attempting the install: Building only for 3.8.0-29-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.8.0-29-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-29-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.100.82.38+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
Can I and how do I consult the log for more information?

Comment: Do you really have 12.04 installed or 13.04? I notice you are using a 3.8 kernel. Consult the log: cat  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/5.100.82.38+bdcom/build/make.log > bcmwl_log.txt. Find the text file in your user directory and post it here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ Your Ubuntu version is probably the key here.

Comment: Here's the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6063070/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try an earlier bcmwl-kernel-source as mentioned here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1110139/comments/42 With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: Thank you all so much! That fix worked for me and Ubuntu is sensing the wireless network now without any problems. I appreciate it!