# Strange wifi trouble caused by update?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t connect to any wireless connection after updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247993/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-connection-after-updating)

My wifi connection has been working flawlessly for 2 years running first ubuntu 11.04 and gradually upgrading to 12.04. A few days ago the connection to my router suddenly stopped working after a restart (it had been connected right up until the restart). The network icon on top shows that it is trying to connect and after a while it stops and tells me I am disconnected. All other devices (6-7 or so) connected to the router continue to access as usual so I do not think it has anything to do with the router itself. Also I found out that I have no problem connecting to the hotspot of my cell phone. Both on my cell and on the router I have WPA-PSK, but I guess that they would be using different standards (n on router versus b/g when using phone hotspot?).

Any ideas on what the problem might be? Tips on how to debug it? I did install the latest upgrades through synaptic prior to restarting, can I have upgraded to a broken driver or something?

Here is the info from lshw -C:

```
*-network
beskrivning: Trådlöst gränssnitt
produkt: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
tillverkare: Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:44:00.0
logiskt namn: eth1
version: 01
serienummer: ac:81:12:3d:93:9a
bredd: 64 bits
klocka: 33MHz
förmågor: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be a bug in the "bcmwl-kernel-source"-package this helped me out!

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/923809/comments/25