# WiFi is not working in Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, wireless, xubuntu

My laptop is Dell Vostro 2520. I tried both Xubuntu and Ubuntu  on it,  I've used 12.04 & 12.10. WiFi fails to work in all the cases - when i try to switch WiFi by a hotkey (fn+f2) the Bluetooth icon appears in the system tray but the light for the WiFi on lower left corner panel doesn't turn on.
I tried the solution of connecting to the network via cable:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

from the similar thread [How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working/215342#215342)

Could you help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Update 1
It wasn't clear to me is @mikewhateve  talking about one or two commands in the console. i tried both

```
halfros@halfros-Vostro-2520:~$ lspci -nn | grep Net, rfkill list all
grep: rfkill: No such file or directory
grep: list: No such file or directory
grep: all: No such file or directory
halfros@halfros-Vostro-2520:~$ lspci -nn | grep Net
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
halfros@halfros-Vostro-2520:~$ rfkill list all
halfros@halfros-Vostro-2520:~$
```

**Update 2**

```
$ sudo dpkg -i | grep bcmwl-kernel-source
dpkg: error: --install needs at least one package archive file argument

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
halfros@halfros-Vostro-2520:~$
```

**Update 3**

```
 dpkg -l grep bcmwl-kernel-source
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  grep           2.12-2       amd64        GNU grep, egrep and fgrep
dpkg-query: no packages found matching bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Can you add the outputs of the following to the question: `lspci -nn | grep Net`, `rfkill list all`. To get the outputs, open a terminal window, copy paste a command, and hit Enter.

Comment: Yes, thank you. i'll do that. I worked on the desktop ubuntu/xubuntu for quite a while now. But the first time i'm setting up a laptop.

Comment: So, it's a BCM43142. It should actually work in 12.04.2 now, with the very recently updated `bcmwl-kernel-source` version 6.20.155.1, but I don't think that 12.10 will get it. You can check the installed version with `dpkg -l | grep bcmwl-kernel-source`. If it's an older version, deactivate it, and try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560).

Comment: please see update 2

Comment: `dpkg -l` <--that's a small L, not i and not one, though they look very similar indeed. Copy/paste, and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @mikewhatever the answer was found. i copy it here to save time for anyone interested in this issue

If you have a 64-bit system and the device I mentioned, then I suggest this package: http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb

First install the prerequisites:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
> ```

Then install the package with:

```
 cd Desktop   <--or whemikewatrever you downloaded the deb
    sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb
    sudo modprobe wl
```