# Why can't I download bcmwl-kernel-source?

Tags: wireless

I have a wireless issue with my HP netbook.

I found a fix here: [How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working)
but when I type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` it tells me that bcmwl-kernel-source could not be downloaded! Any suggestions?

The command `lspci -nn` gives me the number `14e4:4727` for the controller, so that's why I thought this fix above would help.

(I am using Ubuntu 12.10.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx) Look for the 4313 models.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` first, then try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`. If that doesn't help, post the actual error output.

Comment: Connect via an Ethernet (also known as LAN) cable to run the commands so it can download.  Once you have run the commands unplug to test.  If it does not work post the output of these commands.

Comment: I get the same error:family@family-HP-Pavilion-dm1-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of bcmwl-kernel-source is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
family@family-HP-Pavilion-dm1-Notebook-PC:~$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1427221.html

I solve my "No WiFi Adapter found" + the same "cannot download" probleme by following this :

In terminal type the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/bcmwl-kernel-source.{postinst,prerm,postrm}
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get clean
```

then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
reboot
```

**And Finally reinstall with the GUI** :

Open hardware drivers and activate the broadcom STA wireless driver which should be there.