# Why does Wireless on my OEM 32bit notebook not work?

Tags: wireless

[image]I tried this

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

didnt work.

My System: OEM 32bit notebook 2GB RAM, Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Please have a look at the "related" section and see what commands  users are told to use and add those with the results into your question. Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working?rq=1

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this really depends on what kind of (old/new) hardware you have.

There may be some hint in /var/log/syslog.

Please paste here more information (from "lspci" and/or hwinfo) as suggested above.

You can also try looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Tips_and_tricks

and/or possibly finding already existing bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: lightning@rigel5:~$  hwinfo
The program 'hwinfo' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install hwinfo
lightning@rigel5:~$ sudo apt-get hwinfo
[sudo] password for lightning: 
E: Invalid operation hwinfo
lightning@rigel5:~$

Comment: after a restart it worked.... not sure  why

Comment: hwinfo now works as well...bug?