# Problems with internet connection after installing and updating Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 12 on my notebook, and when want to browse on 
internet, I am getting the following error:

"FireFox can't find the server at start.ubuntu.com"

When I installed the Ubuntu, I was connected to internet and everything was OK.
After installation I did some updates and afterwards I am getting this message.

I tied to follow the [same question on this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174231/firefox-cant-find-server-at-start-ubuntu-com) , and tried all advices in comments with no result.Duplicate question is not closed.

- want to connect with WIFI
- if you need more technical information, e.g. from ifconfig, just let me know.

Thank you

EDIT:

1. using Ubuntu 12.10
2. network indicator - indicating no wifi connection at all
   after click - can update/modify existing network connections
3. typing in terminal: ping google.com, => getting message: unname host google.com

Comment: I suggest that you modify the title of your question: your problem is not with Firefox, but with Internet connection. Also, please provide the following information: (i) which Ubuntu version (12.04 or 12.10?) (ii) are you connected to the WiFi (what happens when you click on the network indicator in the top bar)? (iii) what happens when you open a terminal and type "ping google.com"

Comment: What dns addresses you are using ? try using 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it is fixed, I followed this thread:[wireless not working after installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working) .
It seems that you have to install some new drivers for wifi....