# Installed lubuntu 14.04 on an Acer Aspire 5517 and can't connect to wireless

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

```
$ iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

$ ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:5a:b6:08:b3:21  
          inet addr:192.168.1.25  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::725a:b6ff:fe08:b321/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11030 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:5
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8673692 (8.6 MB)  TX bytes:1339434 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:787813 (787.8 KB)  TX bytes:787813 (787.8 KB)
```

But `lspci` sees the Broadcom device:

```
$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen some users with the same card having the same problem ([Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers))

A known issue is that jockey; also known as Additional Drivers, suggests the wrong driver for a few Broadcom cards.

Please open a terminal and run and post:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After it's done, do:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

If there is no error or warning, your wireless should be working.

*OP indicates that an additional step was required to get this solution working.  See below*

After following all of the steps here, I had to additionally install the b43 firmware package like so:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Then it worked after a reboot.

Comment: @Oldschool-Aspire-5517:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H106.00 Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e01b]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet [1969:1062] (rev c0)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:028d] Kernel driver in use: atl1c

Comment: After running your previous suggestion: $ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wl -e firmware -e wlan0 | tail -n35   I got information on firmware that was needed.

Comment: The output of your commands gives me the idea that this seems to be the same situation as some users before as I said. http://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/how-do-i-get-an-acer-npilfy-802-11-wireless-card-working  Should be helpful.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>