# No internet after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet

I just bought me a new lenovo thinkpad 11e and installed ubuntu 12.04 from a bootable USB device. While installing, and also when I am trying ubuntu directly from the USB device, my netbook recognizes all available WLAN connections and is also able to connect.

However, after installation by booting normally my computer is unable even to detect any WLAN.

I tried the answer suggested in

[How do I get an Acer Npilfy 802.11 (BCM43225) wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/how-do-i-get-an-acer-npilfy-802-11-bcm43225-wireless-card-working)

which seems to be related to my problem, but it did not help.

Any help from your side would be greatly appreciated. If there is any other information you need, please let me know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is very old.  There is a great possibility your newer hardware is not supported properly.  I would advise you to install the latest Ubuntu 16.04 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I was installing ubuntu 16.04 now and everythings is fine.  :-)